# Yii2 assets on partial view not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I've a problem with a partial view loaded by ajax in Yii2. This view have an asset registered (css and javascript) and when the view are loaded via ajax at the first time the script work right, from the second time the script not working more, someone understand the problem and how i can solve it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Yii, but it has to do with the way you are binding your javascript events with jquery.

So, in your JS file that handles the events for ajax loaded content, instead of code like
`$('selector').on('event name', function(){})`
use
`$(document).on('event name', 'selector', function(){})`

Read more at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on script for use the `.on()` events handler and seems it work, only one more detail, often I use a `.find()` function on the container element, also this function have to be applied at `$(document)`  otherwise the script not work right

Comment: P.s.:I think this has something to do with Yii, the partial view is loaded with script registered by `renderAjax`, this mean that the script is loaded with view when i run ajax call but all request are processed by Yii before jQuery scripts, I've consider that this is not a classic render or pratialRender